# Formating Response from server in a php array

Tags: php, variables

I´m setting up a new service integrate with verotel, I need to format the response from the server in a PHP array.

I had test some codes to formating the respnse but I can do it. Mi code to get the response is this:

```
$url= $statusURL;
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $result=curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch); 
 echo (array($result));
```

I get from the server this response:

```
response: FOUND

shopID: 114500
paymentMethod: Credit Card
priceAmount: 20
priceCurrency: USD

type: purchase
```

and I need to format it as a PHP array.

Comment: This is the exact response you receive? A text response without a standardized structure (json, xml, etc)? Converting this to an array of key/value pairs is not difficult, but does the response include more than one record or is each response exactly one unit/record?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Verotel, but they seem to have a PHP library on GitHub, why not use that? https://github.com/verotel/flexpay-php-client

Comment: Yes i,m use https://github.com/verotel/flexpay-php-client but when i get the order in postback.php or success.php i do a request to verotel to get all details about the sale and the response form server is this text without format. The response only have one record.

Answer (score 0):

- The first way: This is the `yaml` format, you can use `yaml_parse` to parse it(you need `yaml` extension installed).
- Second: Read as line, then determine if line is empty, `explode` it if not empty and put the result to an array.

Comment: i'm not using yaml. We have our own soft, i need to conver it to a array or similar to after insert the values in a database table.